# BeanIO reading field from CSV which represents a collection

Tags: java, csv, bean-io

I have a CSV file with `;` delimiter, but in one of the fields it represents objects with `|` delimiter:

```
field1;field2;field3;"field-4.1;field-4.2|field-4.1;field-4.2";field5;field6;
```

So the problem is with `field4` which represents multiples objects separated by pipe.

Actually my template is like this:

```
           <record name="fields" class="br.com.beanio.MyPojo">
                <field name="field1"/>
                <field name="field2"/>
                <field name="field3"/>
                <segment name="fields4" minOccurs="0" collection="list" class="br.com.beanio.MySubPojo">
                    <field name="field4-1" />
                    <field name="field4-2" />
                </segment>
                <field name="field5"/>
                <field name="field6"/>
            </record>
```

I tried with different properties to identify when field4 represents a new object, but didn't work.

How could I read field 4 using beanIO templating?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know of something out of the box that could do that. It would be nice perhaps if you could specify a different delimiter for the segment, but that is not possible AFAIK. You could of course just do the parsing of `field4` in a setter method to populate the `br.com.beanio.MySubPojo` or if it is a big object, why not create a separate mapping file and then parse `field4` only with BeanIO? It may not be worth the extra effort.

Comment: I'm trying now to use typeHandler. Do you know if its possible to don't split the "field4"? For example, ignore only in this field?

Comment: You should get back `"field-4.1;field-4.2|field-4.1;field-4.2"` for field4 by default. A `TypeHandler` is a good alternative to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was creating a typeHandler for the field:

```
public class MyCustomTypeHandler implements TypeHandler {
```

In my template I use the typeHandler:

```
<field name="fieldWithList" typeHandler="MyCustomTypeHandler"/>
```

So inside parse method in the typeHandler I could process the field:

```
        if (nonNull(text)) {
            asList(text.split("\\|")).forEach(str -> {
                String[] fields = str.split(";", -1);
                // process and add items to the list
            });
        }
```